# Получить данные из foreign key

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, foreign-key

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с проблемой, никак не могу получить данные из foreign key. проштудировал всё, что только смог найти. Дефолтных примеров не хватает. Не могу перенести логику кода в свой код.

Я хочу создать 2 бд. 1 Корзина 2 список товаров.  foreign key из таблицы Корзины ссылаться на  товар (надеюсь, что он ссылается. и эту часть я написал правильно). в последней строчке я крайне не уверен.

```
class UserCart(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sneakers.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


class Sneakers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    brand = db.Column(db.String(20), default=None, nullable=False)
    series = db.Column(db.String(20), default=None, nullable=False)
    sizes = db.Column(db.String(50), default=None)
    prise = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(db.String(20), default=None, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), default=None)
    photos_tg_id = db.Column(db.String(100), default=None)
    photo_url = db.Column(db.String(200), default=None)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

    cart_id = db.relationship('UserCart', backref='sneakers')
```

Возможно, метод сохранения не корректный -

```
boots = Sneakers(brand='new balance', series='10', prise=12290, color='gray', sizes='40-45')
                db.session.add(boots)

                user_id = 88888888
                i = Sneakers.query.filter(Sneakers.brand == 'new balance').first()
                add_to_cart = UserCart(user_id=user_id, sneakers=i)
                db.session.add(add_to_cart)
                db.session.flush()
                db.session.commit()
                db.session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё же мне удалось понять в чём проблема.

в той самой строчке, которая у меня вызвала подозрения. т.к я не мог понять как её использовать. но именно эта переменная

бывшая(cart_id)

```
sneakers = db.relationship('UserCart', backref='sneakers', lazy='dynamic')
```

и её использование в

```
i = UserCart.query.first()
print(i.sneakers.brand) # new balance
```

даёт доступ к значениям из "Корзины"